# DT editable = "column" not functional

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In the examples on https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/, when `editable = "column"` the results won't render and be retained in the table. Indeed, they only work if `editable = TRUE` or `editable = "cell"`.

From the following code culled from link above, I added a `Click` button to see what was in `input` elements.

When you `Click` following selecting a cell with `editable = "column"` (which allows input to column cells), no changes re seen in `input$x1_columns_selected`.

Can anyone specify why and if this used to work correctly? I cannot see how a feature like this would be broken, it seems very useful.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
    hr(),
    actionButton("click_action", "Click"),
    hr(),
    DTOutput(id)
  ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Double-click to edit table cells',

    dt_output('client-side processing (editable = "column")', 'x1'),
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d1 = iris[1:5,]
    d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))

    # client-side processing

    output$x1 = render_dt(d1, 'column', FALSE)

    observe(str(input$x1_cell_edit))

    observeEvent(input$click_action, {
      print(input)
      print(input$x1_cells_selected)
      print(input$x1_columns_selected)
      print(input$x1_rows_all)
      print(input$x1_rows_current)
      print(input$x1_rows_selected)
      print(input$x1_search)
      #print(input$x1_state)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I filed a related issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/928) a while ago. So far no response.

Comment: OK great, hadn't seen that. Hopefully someone get's back about it soon.

Answer (score 0):

## Editing columns

It turns out that this does work; it's just that clicking out of the cell isn't enough to register the edit.  But pressing Ctrl + Enter works.  (I learned this from the mouseover text of Table 2 on [this page of examples](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).)  So, for example, suppose you edit `Sepal.Width` and set the first value to 7:

[image]

After you press Ctrl + Enter, your app gives this output:

```
 NULL
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ row  : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ col  : int  2 2 2 2 2
 $ value: chr  "7" "3" "3.2" "3.1" ...
```

Meaning that rows 1-5 of column 2 were edited, and their values were set to 7 (a changed value), 3 (same as before), 3.2, etc.

## Selected columns

The value stored in `input$x1_columns_selected` doesn't relate to editing columns.  Rather, if the table has the `selection = list(target = 'column')` option set, an entire column can be selected when the user clicks on it.  In that case, your `Click` button will print the index of the selected column.  Here's an example of the app with that option set (and with the output of the `Click` button limited to just the selected columns):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
    hr(),
    actionButton("click_action", "Click"),
    hr(),
    DTOutput(id)
  ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = list(target = 'column'), server = server,
           editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Double-click to edit table cells',
    
    dt_output('client-side processing (editable = "column")', 'x1'),
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d1 = iris[1:5,]
    d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))
    
    # client-side processing
    
    output$x1 = render_dt(d1, 'column', FALSE)
    
    observe(str(input$x1_cell_edit))
    
    observeEvent(input$click_action, {
      print(input$x1_columns_selected)
    })
  }
)
```

If you click anywhere in the `Sepal.Width` column, you see this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

And then, if you click the button, you get this output:

```
 NULL
[1] 2
```

Meaning that column 2 is selected.